# Laravel querybuilder cant group by

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

This query works with group by

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT  SUM(pending) as total ,  datediff(NOW(), created_at) 
as maturity FROM `admin_case_info` WHERE deleted_at is NULL group by maturity "));
```

But when I joined 2 tables.

```
$data = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT admin_case_info.case_type, admin_case_info.case_status, SUM(admin_case_info.pending) as total, 
datediff(NOW(), admin_case_info.created_at) as maturity FROM admin_case_info 
JOIN users_mws on users_mws.id = admin_case_info.users_mws_id
JOIN users on users.id = users_mws.user_id
 WHERE users.status NOT IN ('Dumped', 'Dumped2')
AND admin_case_info.deleted_at IS NULL group by maturity") );
```

It does not work. I need to modify the `config/database` strict to `false` in order it to work and I dont want to do it. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: `group by maturity` should be extended to group by all non-aggregated selected fields i.e. `GROUP BY maturity, admin_case_info.case_type, admin_case_info.case_status` .

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same expression for group by maturity is not been used properly.

```
$data = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT admin_case_info.case_type, admin_case_info.case_status, SUM(admin_case_info.pending) as total, 
datediff(NOW(), admin_case_info.created_at) as maturity FROM admin_case_info 
JOIN users_mws on users_mws.id = admin_case_info.users_mws_id
JOIN users on users.id = users_mws.user_id
 WHERE users.status NOT IN ('Dumped', 'Dumped2')
AND admin_case_info.deleted_at IS NULL group by datediff(NOW(), admin_case_info.created_at)") );
```